# I'm having this error in Google Play Console android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException but I don't use SQLite in my App

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

By first time I'm seeing this error into Andriod Vitals of Google Play Console:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.1:529)
>   at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run
>   (Unknown Source:2)   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
>   (Handler.java:873)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:99)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7063)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (RuntimeInit.java:494)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:965)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAnd...
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run
>   (Unknown Source:4)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call
>   (Executors.java:459)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
>   (FutureTask.java:266)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run
>   (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFacto...
>   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.start   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$1.run
>   (Unknown Source:8)   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$2.call (Unknown
>   Source:2)   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAnd...
>
> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException:
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement
>   (Native Method)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement
>   (SQLiteConnection.java:1229)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString
>   (SQLiteConnection.java:842)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode
>   (SQLiteConnection.java:490)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration
>   (SQLiteConnection.java:460)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open
>   (SQLiteConnection.java:296)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open
>   (SQLiteConnection.java:215)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked
>   (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:705)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open
>   (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:272)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open
>   (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:239)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner
>   (SQLiteDatabase.java:1292)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open (SQLiteDatabase.java:1247)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase
>   (SQLiteDatabase.java:903)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase
>   (SQLiteDatabase.java:893)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked
>   (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:355)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase
>   (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)   at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.start

In my App I use Firebase, but not SQLite.

Why this error appears? How I can prevent this type of errors? In the error trace not appear references to my source code!

The error was appeared only for one user with this device: `Samsung Galaxy A40 (a40), Android 9`

Comment: Read the error carefully.  The problem is happening through your use of Firestore.  But since we can't see your code, there's not much for us to say.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson The error message don't indicate **the file** or **the line of the error**. In all the code that works with firebase there are not trouble, i do a test of all this coder and not errors occuors. If you see the error message, after the 3rd block it refers to SQLite, i don't understand why, if I not implementing SQLite in this app? I don't know where I can see for this error in my code.